# Get index of sorted duplicate elements in python collection counter

Tags: python, counter

I have sorted collection counter and I'm trying to get the index of `banana` which is 1 because the frequency of `cherry` and `banana` are the same, but it gives 2. Or the index of `mango` must be 2 instead of 3.

**My code:**

```py
from collections import Counter
    
fruits = ['apple','cherry', 'apple','banana','banana','cherry','apple', 'mango']
fruits_frequency = Counter([item for items, c in Counter(fruits).most_common() for item in [items] * c])

print(fruits_frequency)
mapping = dict((item[1][0], item[0]) for item in enumerate(fruits_frequency.most_common()))

print(mapping["banana"])
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'apple': 3, 'cherry': 2, 'banana': 2, 'mango': 1})
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with dictionary comprehension

```
mapping = {x[0]: idx for idx, group in enumerate(groupby(fruits_frequency.items(), lambda x: x[1])) for x in group[1]}
print(mapping)
```

**Output:**

```
{'apple': 0, 'cherry': 1, 'banana': 1, 'mango': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapping = dict((item[1][0], item[0]) for item in enumerate(sorted(fruits_frequency.most_common(),  key=lambda y: (y[1], y[0]))))
```

use sorting for the `fruits_frequency.most_common()` part, by using the key parameter of sorting: `key=lambda y: (y[1], y[0])` essentially first sorting by the number of occurances and the alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to get, you probably want to get a sorted list of the distinct `fruit_frequencies` values and then find find the index of the `bananas` value in that.

Like this:

```
distinct_values = sorted(list(set(fruits_frequency.values())), reverse=True)
print(distinct_values.index(mapping["banana"]))
```